# Two Django apps, and Two different servers

Tags: django

I' have two Django applications on two different servers.
Server A = Regular Django App
Server B = Django Based Rest API

My question is how can I fetch the data from the Server A, using the RestAPI. This way I  can keep the API and the other Django apps separate.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9A0oY.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming each server has there own database and web-server.

One way to do it (without using raw sql) would be if you copy the models from your server A and paste them into server B (possibly with `Meta.managed=False` so it does not generate migration files).

Then in server B add a new database connection in `settings.DATABASES` and fill out the necessary info (like IP, port, user and password) to connect to the database in server A.

This would give server B access to the data on server B (using the copied models).

**BUT:**

1. server B does not see the changes in models you make in server A. You would have to copy those manually.
2. you have to do a lot of copying and pasting.

---

An alternative approach would be to join the code of the two servers so that apps from server B have direct access to the code of the models in server A.

You can keep the databases separate, but join the code as to not repeat your models.

Let me know if this helps you even though its a late answer.